# when to change version number in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, versioning

I know how to change the version number but I wish to know what conditions we change the version number? How it differs from build number?

Do we change version for every minor editing in the code, for example, fixed a small bug? or We change it for major revisions?

Comment: I'm not sure if iOS has some special versioning scheme, but generally you could use [semver](http://semver.org/), if you're given the choice.

Answer (score 2):

Version number for customers,build number for developer.
In my opinion,before every push to Git, let the build number +1. 
I don't change the version number unless I decide to upload my app to iTunes connect. 
And how to change the version number depends on how many features I added or improved since my last build version on iTunes. If I fixed a critical bug that may cause the app crash, let the third number of version +1 and upload it to iTunes as quick as possible.If I just fixed a small bug, I won't upload it and just let build version +1.Too many version updates may cause users annoyed and ignore it.
If there is a new feature added or lots of small bugs fixed, let the second number of version +1 and upload it.
If there are some new features added and some small bugs fixed, it's a brand-new version and I'll let the first version number +1.

Answer (score 0):

The version number is some "encoding" you are going to use to represent where your application is in regards to maturity. Note that I'm trying not to use the word version here in the "definition", so I'm using maturity to represent the state of development your application is in. So a version like 1.0.0 (or 1.0) would in theory represent your first release. As you add features (i.e. application is getting more mature) your version number would change.

How you encode it is up to you, but you commonly see something like:

x.y.z

Where:

- x - Major version
- y - Minor version
- z - Hotfix version

What constitutes major, minor, and hotfix are up to you.

For example, a major version change may be that you completely re-written part of the application to use a newer database. A minor change may be that you added AirPrint support. A hotfix change may be just some bug fixes, but no new added functionality. In general, major and minor will represent feature change(s) or some underlying architecture change(s) whereas hotfixes are more just bug fixes.

Some people don't like to use x.y.z and just use x.y. This is really a matter of preference.

The build version is used during App Store submission to represent your submission attempts.

As stated in the Apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2420/_index.html)

> The Version Number and the Build Number values work together to
>   uniquely identify the build and release for a particular App Store
>   submission. For each new version of your App, you will provide a new
>   unique Version Number and you may provide one or more builds (or
>   submissions) each with a different and unique Build Number together
>   with that same Version Number. All Version Numbers used in an App must
>   be unique. You cannot re-use version numbers. Also, as you create new
>   releases, new Version Numbers must be added in ascending sequential
>   order.
>
> Build Numbers provide a way to name each of the submissions you
>   provide for a particular release. As described in the definitions
>   above, the collection of all of the builds that you provide for a
>   particular version of your App is called that version's 'release
>   train'. Build Numbers must be unique within each release train, but
>   they do not need to be unique across different release trains. That is
>   to say, you can use the same Build Numbers again in different release
>   trains if you want to. And, as you create and submit new builds for a
>   release, the Build Numbers you assign to them must be in ascending
>   sequential order.
>
> It is normal to use the same Version Number many times over and over
>   again with different Build Numbers when uploading submissions for a
>   particular release of your app.

Comment: Do I need to submit ipa again for updated itunes connected version ? I mean if I added 3.11.2 and it is in status as "Prepare for Submission" and I have uploaded build for 3.11.2 it is working and it is in Test flight--- now at some later point my team decides lets have 3.12 without 3.11.2. How this should be handled ?